# While "<li>" <= 20 add empty "<li>"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a `<li>` inside an `<ul>` if the `<li>` count is less or equal to 20, but the code doesn't seem to be working...

I'm using the following jQuery:

```
while ($(".mosaico > li").length() <= 20) {
   $('.mosaico').append('<li>test</li>');
};
```

And nothing seems to happen... The HTML is:

```
<ul class="mosaico">
    <li>
    </li>

    <li>
    </li>

    <li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.length` is a property, not a function.

But you shouldn't run the selector in a loop like that. Just calculate how many you need, and add them all at once.

```
var mosaico = $(".mosaico"),
    len = 20 - mosaico.children('li').length,
    str = '';

while( len-- > 0 ) {
    str += '<li>test</li>';
}

mosaico.append(str);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pQXNT/2

Comment: Should i put the selector in a variable and use that instead?

Comment: @Tiago: I updated my answer to create a single string of tags that gets appended. If `mosaico` is empty to begin with, you can eliminate the `- mosaico.length` part.

Comment: I tried my code with the lenght as property and it worked. Your code isn't appending though, it adds 20... :S

Comment: Should that be `$('.mosaico > li')` ?

Comment: You might have to make sure that `mosaico.children('li').length` is not larger than `20`. Otherwise you have an infinite loop.

Comment: @Tiago: Yes, I just updated. I had forgotten that I changed your selector to remove the `> li`, so I had to add `.children('li')` before `.length`.

Comment: @RightSaidFred at this moment, it is starting with 13 `li` and it is appending 20 more with your code...

Answer (score 3):

length is not a function, leave the `()`

```
while ($(".mosaico > li").length <= 20) {
   $('.mosaico').append('<li>test</li>');
};
```

or do it in a oneliner:

```
 $(".mosaico")
   .append(
       $(new Array( 20 - $(".mosaico li").length + 1 )
         .join('<li>test</li>'))
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.length` instead of `.length()`. Also use some tools for debugging JavaScript, such as Firebug for Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use a for loop

```
for(i=0;i<20;i++)
{
   $('.mosaico').append('<li>test</li>'); 

}
```

Comment: If it already contains `<li>`s doesn't this add 20 anyway? I mean if there are 10 already you'll end up with 30.

Comment: pimvb is correct - the question was about how to add `<li>` elements when they are _less than 20_, not in every case.